# Input string was not in a correct format App crashing

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Well everything worked just fine after i implemented solution from last question I asked, I tryed to empty every entry field once you clicked submit but that didnt work I deleted that code so it is same as before but for some reason it wont work now. App works just fine till moment you erase the value from entry fields. App doesnt allow me to leave those fields empty once you typed something in them. First entry name is eraseble but other 3 aint.
My goal with these app is to get Display prompt with these 3 int values.
This is ViewModel code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Papucometar.ViewModel
{
    public class LoginViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public Action DisplayInvalidLoginPrompt;
        public Action DisplayValidLoginPrompt;
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
        private string Name;
        public string name
        {
            get { return Name; }
            set
            {
                Name = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name"));
            }
        }
        private string LR;
        public string Lr
        {
            get { return LR; }
            set
            {
                if(int.Parse(value) < 1)
                {
                    LR = "1";
                }
                else
                {
                    LR = value;
                }
                
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("LR"));
            }

        }
        private string PI;
        public string Pi
        {
            get { return PI; }
            set
            {
                PI = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("PI"));
            }
        }
        private string R;
        public string r
        {
            get { return R; }
            set
            {
                if(int.Parse(value) < 1)
                {
                    R = "1";
                }
                else
                {
                    R = value;
                }
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("R"));
            }
        }
        public ICommand SubmitCommand { protected set; get; }
        public LoginViewModel()
        {
            SubmitCommand = new Command(OnSubmit);
        }
        public void OnSubmit()
        {
            if(R == null || LR == null || PI == null || Name == null) 
            {
                DisplayInvalidLoginPrompt();
            }
            else
            {
                DisplayValidLoginPrompt();
            }
            
                
        }

    }
}
```

Here is code behind:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
using Papucometar.ViewModel;
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace Papucometar.View
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class LoginUI : ContentPage
    {
        public LoginUI()
        {
            var vm = new LoginViewModel();
            this.BindingContext = vm;
            vm.DisplayInvalidLoginPrompt += () => DisplayAlert("Slamas ga", "Sjebo si ga brate aj opet", "Popravi");
            vm.DisplayValidLoginPrompt += () => DisplayAlert("Nevidjena Papuca", $"{vm.name} je papuca velicine {int.Parse(vm.Lr)*int.Parse(vm.Pi)/int.Parse(vm.r)} bacvi na kvadrat", "Ok");
            InitializeComponent();
            name.Completed += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
            {
                Lr.Focus();
            };

            Lr.Completed += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
            {
                vm.SubmitCommand.Execute(null);
            };
            Pi.Completed += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
            {
                vm.SubmitCommand.Execute(null);
            };
            r.Completed += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
            {
                vm.SubmitCommand.Execute(null);
            };
        }

    }
    

}
```

And this is xaml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Papucometar.View.LoginUI"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Papucometar.ViewModel"
             x:DataType="local:LoginViewModel"
             BackgroundColor="#112B47">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Padding="40" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Image Source="slika.png" WidthRequest="180" HeightRequest="180"></Image>
            <Entry x:Name="name" Text="{Binding name}" Placeholder="Unesite ime papuce" TextColor="White" PlaceholderColor="Gray"></Entry>
            <Entry x:Name="Lr" Text="{Binding Lr, Mode=TwoWay}" Placeholder="Unesite lepotu ribe(1-10)" TextColor="White" PlaceholderColor="Gray"></Entry>
            <Entry x:Name="Pi" Text="{Binding Pi, Mode=TwoWay}"  Placeholder="Unesite koliko puta vas je ispalio" TextColor="White" PlaceholderColor="Gray"></Entry>
            <Entry x:Name="r" Text="{Binding r, Mode=TwoWay}" Placeholder="Unesite koliko puta je ispalio ribu" TextColor="White" PlaceholderColor="Gray"></Entry>
            <Button
                Command="{Binding SubmitCommand}"
                VerticalOptions="Center"
                Text="Izračunaj veličinu papuče"
                TextColor="White"
                BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                BorderColor="OrangeRed"
                BorderWidth="1.5"
                CornerRadius="50">
            </Button>

        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

I wanted to delete values from entry field i just entered when testing app but when I started deleting app crashed.

Comment: You are calling `int.Parse` that will throw exactly that exception if the input string cannot be parsed to an `int` (for instance if it's empty or contais alphabetic characters)

Comment: But int parse wont be called unless button is clicked right?

Comment: You have a two-way binding in your xaml, so yes the setter will execute whenever you change that textbox, maybe even if you just focus and unfocus it

Comment: So would setting mode to one way solve problem?

Comment: No, you should correctly handle invalid input. Use `int.TryParse()` instead

Comment: So if i make an if statemnt with conidtion int.TryParse(value, out x) && x < 1 it should do job? And making it oneway actually worked.

Comment: But this way the value is not propageted from the textbox to the property...

Comment: If you don't need textbox to be initialized from property, you could use `Mode="OneWayToSource"`. Regardless, any time there is user input, its best to use `TryParse` instead of `Parse`. Why risk the possibility of user crashing app with some other bad input? Suppose they type letters instead of numbers? OR you could wrap the code inside `try .. catch`, so an exception is harmless. FWIW: Please take the time to write English as best you can. I realize it may not be your native language, but you surely know that "aint" isn't correct. Write for SO as if you were at a professional job.

Comment: You could set some validations on the entry input using [TextValidationBehavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/behaviors/text-validation-behavior).